# Как сделать раскрытие панели с текстом выше?

Tags: html, css, анимация

```css
:root {
  --surface-color: #fff;
  --curve: 40;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fef8f8;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  gap: 2rem;
  margin: 4rem 26vw;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: calc(var(--curve) * 1px);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.card__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: calc(var(--curve) * 1px);
  background-color: var(--surface-color);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover .card__overlay {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.card__header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: calc(var(--curve) * 1px) 0 0 0;
  background-color: var(--surface-color);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.card__arc {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card__arc path {
  fill: var(--surface-color);
  d: path("M 40 80 c 22 0 40 -22 40 -40 v 40 Z");
}

.card:hover .card__header {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.card__thumb {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card__title {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 .3em;
  color: #6A515E;
}

.card__tagline {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-family: "MockFlowFont";
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #D7BDCA;
}

.card__status {
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #D7BDCA;
}

.card__description {
  padding: 0 2em 2em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #D7BDCA;
  font-family: "MockFlowFont";
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cards">
  <li>
    <a href="" class="card">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oYiTqum.jpg" class="card__image" alt="" />
      <div class="card__overlay">
        <div class="card__header">
          <svg class="card__arc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path /></svg>
          <img class="card__thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/7D7I6dI.png" alt="" />
          <div class="card__header-text">
            <h3 class="card__title">Кокина Эльвира Рашидовна</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="card__description">Образование высшее педагогическое (ФГБОУ ВО «Шадринский государственный педагогический университет», 2016г.). Стаж работы воспитателем – 8 лет.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="" class="card">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2DhmtJ4.jpg" class="card__image" alt="" />
      <div class="card__overlay">
        <div class="card__header">
          <svg class="card__arc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path /></svg>
          <img class="card__thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/sjLMNDM.png" alt="" />
          <div class="card__header-text">
            <h3 class="card__title">Кривошеина Ольга Николаевна</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="card__description">Образование высшее педагогическое («Тобольский государственный педагогический институт имени Д.И.Менделеева», 2003г.). Стаж работы воспитателем – 12 лет. Имеет Благодарственное письмо Департамента образования и науки Тюменской области</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как сделать раскрытие этой панели с текстом выше? чтобы был виден весь текст

Comment: Не понятно, объясни каков должен быть конечный результат...

Comment: @Air  салам скорее всего текст должно быть видно - весь

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/xxqNWqj - так вроде

Comment: а что должно произойти, если текст не помещается на весь блок (много текста)?

Comment: @MaximLensky, привет...

Comment: Тот код что вы представили отрабатывает корректно и блоки смещаются в зависимости от описания верно, там где мало текста смещается меньше, где больше соответственно больше и ничего не срезается, проверяйте другие стили, какой-то из них на вашем портале влияет на отображения данного примера, также поиграйтесь с отступами (margin/padding) класса card__description